# a specific symbol that cannot be reached by normal functions in latex

Tags: symbols

I wish to have a symbol the same as:

[image]

I have tried with `\mathcal` or `mathscr` but they could not get the desired result. How to reach this symbol?

Comment: It's from Lucida Calligraphic, which is not a free font.

Comment: very well thanks for your guidance